# Trying To Run C++ Code, A "Procedure Entry Point" Error Occurred

Tags: c++, string, vector, g++

I've been trying to run this piece of code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<int> s = {0};
    cout << s[0] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

But there is an error that is popping:

[image]

I tried to run it using cmd, by writing

```
g++ Source.cpp
```

Which compiled into `a.exe` and I can't run it.

I tried to replace the `vector` with `string` using the string header (`#include<string>` in the beginning) but got a similar error message.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your code is fine. Compiler command too. This is IDE issue, it seems that you have set your project as a dynamic library?

Comment: what is your .dll version?

Comment: I don't know.
The project itself is in an Atom project, how do I set it as a dynamic library?

Comment: I'm pertty amateur when it comes to programming, I used Visual Studio, but the look and simplicity of Atom are very nice. I learn how to code online as a hobby, and I don't know that a dll is. 

Can you explain those things to me?

Comment: *How* do you try to run your program?

Comment: After compiling it, I wrote it's name in the command prompt (a.exe) and the error message popped up.  I tried to open it using the Windows File Explorer, but same result.

Comment: My guess is you have more than 1 version of mingw runtime installed on your PC. You compile with 1 but when you run from explorer it finds a different runtime in the path.

Comment: Have you tried compiling with any, or a couple, of the flags `-static`, `-static-libgcc` and `-static-libstdc++`?

Comment: Hey Ted, using -static solved it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: The Answer brought by ted helped me!
I wrote

```
g++ -static Source.cpp
```

and then I ran the code flawlessly!

I added it to the compiler options in atom and that works as well!
Thanks guys! I love this community :)